# Avro and java: deserialized map of string doesn't "equals" original map

Tags: java, string, serialization, utf-8, avro

I am testing Avro for java with a simple record composed of a string and a map. Here's my schema:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"TableRecord",
  "fields":[
    {"name":"ActionCode","type":"string"},
    {
      "name":"Fields",
      "type":{"type":"map","values":["string","long","double","null"]}
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's a very simple test case that fails:

```
@Test
public void testSingleMapSerialization() throws IOException {
    final String schemaStr; // see above

    // create some data
    Map<String, Object> originalMap = new Hashtable<>();
    originalMap.put("Ric", "sZwmXAdYKv");
    originalMap.put("QuoteId", 4342740204922826921L);
    originalMap.put("CompanyName", "8PKQ9va3nW8pRWb4SjPF2DvdQDBmlZ");
    originalMap.put("Category", "AvrIfd");

    // serialize data
    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema schema = parser.parse(schemaStr);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
    Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
    GenericRecord datum = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    datum.put("ActionCode", "R");
    datum.put("Map", originalMap);
    writer.write(datum, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
    out.flush();

    // deserialize data
    DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(out.toByteArray(), null);
    datum = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    Map<String, Object> deserializedMap = (Map<String, Object>) reader.read(datum, decoder).get("Map");
    System.out.println(originalMap);
    System.out.println(deserializedMap);
    Assert.assertEquals("Maps data don't match", originalMap, deserializedMap);
}
```

And here's the output of the test:

```
{CompanyName=8PKQ9va3nW8pRWb4SjPF2DvdQDBmlZ, Ric=sZwmXAdYKv, Category=AvrIfd, QuoteId=4342740204922826921}
{QuoteId=4342740204922826921, Category=AvrIfd, CompanyName=8PKQ9va3nW8pRWb4SjPF2DvdQDBmlZ, Ric=sZwmXAdYKv}

java.lang.AssertionError: Maps data don't match expected:<{CompanyName=8PKQ9va3nW8pRWb4SjPF2DvdQDBmlZ, Ric=sZwmXAdYKv, Category=AvrIfd, QuoteId=4342740204922826921}> but was:<{QuoteId=4342740204922826921, Category=AvrIfd, CompanyName=8PKQ9va3nW8pRWb4SjPF2DvdQDBmlZ, Ric=sZwmXAdYKv}>
```

As you can see, the two maps look identical but the test fails. JUnit calls the "equals" method under the covers, and that should return true. BTW, if you're wondering what's the gibberish, I usually create test cases with randomly generated data, so that's where it comes from.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a catch with string serialization/de-serialization I'm not aware of? I searched online with no success.

Ideas?

Thanks

Giodude

Comment: I don't think so. Just try creating two hashtables with the same contents and compare them. You'll get true. Here's the javadoc for the equals method for java.util.Map:

"Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet()). This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Map interface."

Comment: Since entrySet() returns a Set, here's the javadoc for the equals method for Set:

"Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface."

Comment: Can you go through the entry set of the map one-by-one to see which one is failing equality?

Comment: Is it possible that `deserializedMap` is an avro Map implementation that doesn't implement. `equals()` correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what the "catch" was. I was comparing a map containing `java.lang.String`s with one containing `org.apache.avro.util.Utf8`. It turns out the Utf8 equals method doesn't work if used with strings. I realized this by adding to my test case the following:

```
for (Object o : deserializedMap.values())
  System.out.println(o.getClass());
for (Object o : deserializedMap.keySet())
  System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

which prints the following:

```
class java.lang.Long
class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8
```

I guess this was to be expected since Avro always converts strings to its native `Utf8` type. I assumed it would reproduce my map as-is, but that's not the case. It's odd that the type cast to Map succeeded, I am not clear on how that happened.

Comment: Casting to Map<String, Object> ignores the template arguments because that information is not available at runtime.  The compiler should be able to give you a warning about that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Avro map uses org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 as default key since 1.5, and could be changed to String. For more details, you may refer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-803 or [Apache Avro: map uses CharSequence as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728853/apache-avro-map-uses-charsequence-as-key)