# Apache Avro: map uses CharSequence as key

Tags: java, avro

I am using [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/gettingstartedjava.html).

My schema has map type:

```
{"name": "MyData", 
  "type" :  {"type": "map", 
              "values":{
                   "type": "record",
                   "name": "Person",
                   "fields":[
                      {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
                      {"name": "age", "type": "int"},

                ]
                }
               }
}
```

After compile the schema, the genated Java class use `CharSequence` as the **key**  for the `Map`  `MyData`.

It is very inconvenient to use `CharSequence` in `Map` as key, is there a way to generate `String` type key for `Map` in [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/gettingstartedjava.html)?

**P.S.**

Problem is that, for example `dataMap.containsKey("SOME_KEY")` will returns `false` even though there is such key there, just because it is `CharSequence`. Besides, put an map entry with a existing key doesn't relpace the old one. That's why I say it is inconvenient to use `CharSequence` as key.

Comment: Given your comment on the one answer: did you find out exactly what's breaking for you? As in, does the `Map` you get actually use non-`String` keys?

Comment: Millimoose, the generated Map use CharSequence for key.

Comment: The generated map uses Utf8 by default, and you can choose to make it String. CharSequence is just an interface.

Answer (score 12):

[This JIRA discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-803) is relevant. The main point of CharSequence still being used is **backwards-compatability**.

And like Charles Forsythe pointed out, there has been added a workaround for when String is necessary, by setting the string property in the schema.

```
 { "type": "string", "avro.java.string": "String" }
```

The default type here is their own Utf8 class. In addition to manual specification and [the pom.xml setting](http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/ANNOUNCE-Avro-Release-1-6-0-td3472313.html), there is even an avro-tools compile option for it, the `-string` option:

```
java -jar avro-tools.1.7.5.jar compile -string schema /path/to/schema .
```

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, there is a workaround for this problem in Avro 1.6.  You specify the string type in your project's POM file:

```
  <stringType>String</stringType>
```

This is mentioned in this issue is [AVRO-803](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-803) ... though the plugin's web documentation doesn't reflect this.

Comment: According to that issue, to add insult to injury the `CharSequence` subclass used is actually an Avro-specific class (`Utf8`) which they could've easily made hashable/equatable to `String` to reduce some of the pain.

Comment: That's a good point. This might be a worthwhile change for Avro if it hasn't already been added. On the other hand, CharSequence doesn't guarantee the equality behavior, so perhaps it is better to use toString() in those cases anyway.

Comment: @millimoose No, that is not possible.  You can't make it work with String, since the first thing string does is check if the other object passed in equals is String.   No non-string implementation of CharSequence can have hashCode/equals interop properly with String.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, by default, Avro uses `CharSequence`.  I found [a way to configure it to convert to `String`](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/9781449328917/avro/id3794805)

> From Avro 1.6.0 onward, there is an option to have Avro always perform the conversion to String. There are a couple of ways to achieve this. The first is to set the avro.java.string property in the schema to String:

```
         { "type": "string", "avro.java.string": "String" }
```

I have not tested this.

Comment: This is the correct way to do this, and this property is present to deal with this exact problem.

Comment: is this a per field configuration? how do you do this for the map key?
also, the link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of whether it's possible to force Avro to use a `String`, using `CharSequence` directly is a bad implementation because `CharSequence` isn't `Comparable<CharSequence>` and doesn't even specify equality of two identical sequences. I suggest filing this as a bug against Avro.

Comment: In fact even in a fairly trivial case (`String` and `StringBuilder`) the hash codes don't match: http://ideone.com/cX76YN. (They do for `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` but that's probably a consequence of the latter being mostly a copy of the former with synchronisation removed.)

Comment: @millimoose `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` both extend the package-protected `AbstractStringBuilder` so no surprise that they act alike.  Agree that this is an implementation problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think explicitly convert String to Utf8 will work.
"some_key" -> new Utf8("some_key") and use this as your key for the map.

Answer (score -1):

a quick solution(the value type could be other Objects, now I am):

```
Map<String, String> convertToStringMap(Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> map){
    if (null == map){
        return null;
    }
    HashMap<String, String> result = new  HashMap<String, String>();
    for(CharSequence key: map.keySet()){
        CharSequence k_value = map.get(key);
        String s_key = key.toString();
        String s_value = k_value.toString();
        result.put(s_key, s_value);
    }
    return result;
}
```