# MapReduce with Avro in Java: String vs CharSequence vs Utf8 data types

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I'm a beginner in writing Hadoop MapReduce with Avro, and am unclear as to what the differences are between passing in to a map/reduce method a Pair with String, CharSequence, or Utf8?

What if the string is just simply something like "hello world"?

Here's a simple map method for example, in this case using CharSequence as the output key type:

```
public void map(Pair<CharSequence, Integer> datum, AvroCollector<Pair<CharSequence, Integer>> collector, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            Integer number_one = new Integer(1);
            String output_key = "hello world";
            collector.collect(new Pair<CharSequence, Integer>(output_key, one));
        }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

[`CharSequence` is an interface that "bundles"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) most of the character based implementations like `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `CharBuffer`, `String` and in Avro `Utf8`.

`String` is immutable, which means that you can not modify the internal data- every modification you do will result in a new `String` object beeing created.

[`Utf8` on the other hand will allow you to modify its internal buffer ("mutable")](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/util/Utf8.html), this will generate less garbage as opposed to using `String` instances.

So you can say that using `CharSequence` is the most flexible solution, as it allows you to pass many more representations of Strings than a specialized implementation, it is up to you to choose from the available implementations depending on your needs.

Comment: A word of warning related to this question. You're probably going to want to stick to one particular implementation of CharSequence, like String, rather than using the general interface. The hashcodes of different CharSequence implementations do not necessarily match, which can cause problems. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728853/apache-avro-map-uses-charsequence-as-key

Comment: @AlexA. good point, it would destroy the partitioning between map and reduce.