# How to extract Map typed from GenericRecord in Avro?

Tags: java, dictionary, avro

I have a Generic Record as shown below where `holder` is a map with values as string.

```
 {
    "name" : "holder",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "map",
      "values" : "string"
    }
  }
```

And below is the data for holder map:

```
"holder": {
    "cossn": "0",
    "itwrqm": "20003"
}
```

And I want to extract holder data in a Map of String and String. I am not sure how can I do that? I tried two options as shown below:

This return object:

```
GenericRecord record = decoder.decode(data.value());    
Object holder = record.get("holder");
```

This returns Map but I don't really see it is a map of key and value.

```
GenericRecord record = decoder.decode(data.value());    
Map<String, String> holder = (Map<String, String>) record.get("holder");
```

When I print `holder` I see like this which is clearly not a map of key/value. What is wrong I am doing? And how to extract map typed from GenericRecord?

```
{cossn=0, itwrqm=200006033213}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use

```
HashMap<Utf8, Utf8> holder = (HashMap<Utf8, Utf8>) record.get("holder");
```

and access your holder items via

```
String itwrqm = holder.get(new Utf8("itwrqm")).toString();
```

Avro uses Utf8 Class for string representation internally.
Another workaround would be to change your Schema to support the Java String representation in Avro:

```
{
"name" : "holder",
"type" : "type": {"type": "map", "values": {"type" : "string","avro.java.string": "String"},
         "avro.java.string":"String"} 
}
```

With that Schema you could use a `HashMap<String,String>` to get your holder map.
See [Apache Avro: map uses CharSequence as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728853/apache-avro-map-uses-charsequence-as-key) for further instructions.